# Web method response format in Mono2.0.1

Tags: web-services, json, mono, asmx

I wrote a [WebMethod] that return a string that store a serialized object

```
[WebMethod]
public string doStuffs() {
...
return JavaScriptConvert.SerializeObject(myObj); 
// JSON Serializer library is JSON.NET 1.3.1, for MONO
}
```

When I call the method with a $.post from JQuery:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/web/doStuffs",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      // Do stuffs
    }
  });
```

The problem is the response. Here what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://localhost:8080/papi">{
 "field1" : "value1", "field2 : "value2", etc etc}</string>
```

Why JSON response has been encapsulated inside an XML? I can see from HTTP Response header is (wrongly?) set to:

```
Content-Type text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

How do I switch the response content type? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have experience with Mono so I'll just comment. If your doStuffs() is a .Net web method, it might serialize its result as XML automatically. This is the case with ASP.Net .asmx web methods at least.

Comment: ASFIK yes, it automatically serialize in XML. I am looking for a way to switch to JSON.

Comment: What benefits does a WebMethod offer if you disable its serializing? I'm not sure that it is possible to skip the serialization step of WebMethod as that's more or less its main point. Or is this known to be possible? I believe even the url of "web/doStuffs" requires JSON functionality from the framework as the normal SOAP has only one endpoint and specifies the method in its body.

Comment: An alternative would be to use a raw ashx http handler if Mono supports those.

Answer (score 1):

If I do:

```
$.post(
    "/web/doStuffs",
    { username: $("#username").val() },
    function(data){
      var obj = $(data).children();
    },           
    "xml"
);
```

I will have JSON in var obj ready to get parsed with JS. This should work well.

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of JSON though?

Answer (score 1):

Does Mono support [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)?

UPDATE: [it would appear so](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg59844.html), but maybe there are bugs?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK WebMethods return objects which get serialized automatically by ASP.NET. The default serializer is SOAP, as that used to be the expected format for web services.

However, ASP.NET AJAX in System.Web.Extensions has a replacement handler that uses a JSON serializer. See http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/04/aspnet-ajax-in-mono.html for how to register it.